# How to remove pink pixels from weather radar pngs downloaded at runtime?

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, fragment-shader, png

I have some radar imagery that comes from a source that has a bug in it's rendering system. Pink is supposed to be the separation of specific cloud consistencies BUT it often shows up on the edges of clouds due to this bug. These pngs are downloaded in real time to live on materials for the duration of my app. The png's consist of color and alpha (where all the black is)

I have two ideas

- A) Process the png upon download (background thread) removing all the pink from the outside of edges of pixels
- B) Add instruction to my existing shader to remove any pink that exists with 2-3 pixels of a transparent pixel

1. Is option B even possible and 2. Is there a better more obvious option that I'm missing ?

[image: radar image with unwanted residue]

** EDIT **

(from comments below)
"*Essentially the little squiggles of pink near the edges of clouds is erroneous and should be gone. the largest cluster of pink at the top is correct & should stay and it's fine if the edge pixels use their nearest green/blue color (even no color [alpha0] would be better than the pink)*"

Correct radar imagery (not sporadic squiggles of pink on the edges of cloud)
[image: correct radar image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what this image should look like when processed correctly. Can you mock up an offline example of what output is desired for a specific input?

Comment: Essentially the little squiggles of pink near the edges of clouds is erroneous and should be gone. the largest cluster of pink at the top is correct & should stay and it's fine if the edge pixels use their nearest green/blue color (even no color [alpha0] would be better than the pink)

Comment: my knee-jerk solution is to do a nearest-neighbor check for small clusters of pink, then a nearest-neighbor alpha check to see if the pink is at an edge. that seems like it would be incredibly slow so I'm hoping there's a better way.